# Apache: VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

When I add the following line to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, I get the error below after I restart apache:

```
Include
/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/examples/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

> [Mon Jun 14 12:16:47 2010] [error]
>   VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and
>   non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost
>   address is not supported, proceeding
>   with undefined results [Mon Jun 14
>   12:16:47 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost
>   *:80 has no VirtualHosts

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName tirengarfio.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/rs3

   <Directory /var/www/rs3>
      AllowOverride All
      Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      Allow from All
   </Directory>

   Alias /sf /var/www/rs3/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
   <Directory "/var/www/rs3/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another NameVirtualHost entry in your http.conf that's causing this issue. Look for an entry like `NameVirtualHost *:*` somewhere, and removing that should remove that error.

Also, as a side note, it's probably not a good idea to include httpd-vhosts.conf directly from the example documentation, since depending on the permissions it might not be particularly secure. It's also not where other people would expect it to be, although if you're the only one managing the server that becomes less of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably another VirtualHost that interferes with the one you are trying to define. It can be defined in sites-available, sites-enabled or apache2.conf. The VHost definition should look like

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 
NameVirtualHost *:81

<VirtualHost *:80>
# ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you copy configuration file into /etc directory. Anyway, search (see below) if there is another virtualhost directive in any apache configuration files.

grep -lir virtualhost /etc/apache2

(I guess all apache configuration files are in /etc/apache2 directory)